# login page not working in phonegap with php

Tags: php, android, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap-plugins

Hello friends i am new in Phonegap and i am make simple login application with **PHP**.
i have type of file like:

1. index.html
2. mob_login.php
3. cordova.xml

so my problem is when i run my program on phonegap in android my **mob_login.php** file is not working.

- in my index.html file my url is **url: "http://10.0.0.2/mob_login.php"** and my PHP file on my local host. how can access this file on my phonegap.
- and in my cordova.xml file i change the **access origin="http://10.0.0.2*"**
- so please tall me where is change my file and how can i solve error.

my index.html file is :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PhoneGap Login</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function login() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

            $(document).ready(function() {
                              var user = $("#user")[0].value;
                              var pass = $("#pass")[0].value;

                              $("#message")[0].value = "In function "+user +"  "+ pass;                                      
                              $.ajax({
                                     type: "POST",
                                     url: "http://10.0.0.2/mob_login.php",
                                     data: "users"+user+"&pass="+pass,

                                     success: function(result){

                                     $("#message")[0].value = result;
                                     alert("Result "+result);
                                     }
                                     });
        });
                              }
        </script>



</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Username: <input type="text" size="25" id="user"/>
        <br />
        Password: <input type="text" size="25" id="pass"/>
        <br />
        <input type="text" size="25" id="message" value="error message" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="login()"/>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my mob_login.php file is :-

```
<?php
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];

if($pass == "123" && $user == "kirit"){
    echo "Login Sucsess";
} else {
    echo "Login Fail";
}
?>
```

and my cordova.xml file is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<cordova>
    <access origin="http://10.0.0.2*"/> 
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
    <preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
</cordova>
```

this is my file and how can i solve the problem please i try to many way but i can't solve please any buddy help me?

Comment: my  mob_login.php file isn't working. it is on localhost and not get the output.

Comment: hello friends can u solve my problem please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
u placed users in ajax code instead of "user=" try below code    


$.ajax({
                                 type: "POST",
                                 url: "http://ipaddress of ur system/JQuery/mob_login.php",
                                 data: "user="+user+"&pass="+pass,

                                 success: function(result){

                                 $("#message")[0].value = result;
                                 alert("Result "+result);
                                 }
                                 });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to make the AJAX call on click, not when the document has finished loading. Here is one problem:

```
var user = $("#user")[0].value;
var pass = $("#pass")[0].value;
```

This code is executed when the page is loaded, but right in that moment, the user and pass inputs have empty values. You need to change your code to make this assignment when you click the login button.

Moreover, you could remove the 'ready' listener, and just write the login function like so:

```
function login() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

    var user = $("#user").val();
    var pass = $("#pass").val();

    $("#message").text("In function "+user +"  "+ pass);                                      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.0.0.2/mob_login.php",
        data: "users"+user+"&pass="+pass,

        success: function(result) {

            $("#message")[0].value = result;
            alert("Result "+result);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem in your code is that when the login function gets called, the ready event has already been dispatched, so the ajax request never gets sent to the server.

Hope this helps. Have a great day.

Comment: thanx friend but it is not working in my php file what can i do? my php file on localhost and i am trying to call by url. so my url is correct or not when i run my ajex function is not work.

Comment: Which server are you running? Did you try using localhost in your url?

Comment: I have edited some parts of the code. Mainly, the segment where jQuery loads the login data, and the "message" trace. Let me know if it works.